# Alternative to subprocess.Popen.communicate() for streaming

Tags: python, io, subprocess

If I'm using [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) I can use `communicate()` for small outputs.

But if the subprocess is going to take substantial time and produce substantial output, I want to access it as streaming data.

Is there a way to do this? The Python docs say

> Warning: Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

I would really like to access a process output as a file-like object:

```
with someMagicFunction(['path/to/some/command','arg1','arg2','arg3']) as outpipe:
   # pass outpipe into some other function that takes a file-like object
```

but can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`communicate` is a convenience method that starts background threads to read `stdout` and `stderr`. You can just read `stdout` yourself, but you need to figure out what to do with `stderr`. If you don't care about errors, you could add the param `stderr=open(os.devnull, 'wb')` or to a file `stderr=open('somefile', 'wb')`. Or, create your own background thread to do the read. It turns out that `shutil` already has such a function, so we can use it.

```
import subprocess
import threading
import shutil
import io

err_buf = io.BytesIO()

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
err_thread = threading.Thread(target=shutil.copyfileobj, 
    args=(proc.stderr, err_buf))
err_thread.start()
for line in proc.stdout:
    print(line.decode('utf-8'), end='')
retval = proc.wait()
err_thread.join()
print('error:', err_buf.getvalue())
```